# How to plot a graph from two lists of data, range or array

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to do a numerical integration in Mathematica for a basic spring problem. In short, I calculate in loop and save two list of numbers (values of times and positions) and after loop, I want to draw results, with X-axis being a time and Y-axis being a position. Can you help me how to plot this graph when using `Range[]` to save numbers?

I am also open to recommendations for improvement of code, how would it be more optimal to save this kind of data, would you recommend me using `Array[]`, `Table[]` or `Range[]`?

Thanks.

```
 (* Initial Conditions*)
x0=1;
v0=0;
t0=0;
t=2*Pi;

(*Parameters*)
k=1;
m=1;

h=.1;    (*Step size *)
n = IntegerPart[(t-t0)/h];(* Number of steps *)

(*Miscellenous For Drawing*)
tList = Range[n+1];
tList[[1]]=t0;
xList  = Range[n+1];
xList[[1]]=x0;
vList= Range[n+1];
vList[[1]]=v0;
x=x0;
v=v0;

For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
vdot= -( k*x)/m;  (* Linear Momentum Balance Equation*)
x = x + v*h;      (* Euler's Method *)
v = v + vdot*h;   (* Euler's Method *)
tList[[i+1]]=i*h;
xList[[i+1]]=x;
vList[[i+1]]=v;
]

Plot[tList,xList] (*???Basically it does not work so I need help with this line*)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pretty close.
You can combine your two lists with `txList = Transpose[{tList, xList}]`
And then do `ListPlot[txList]`
[image]

Nothing wrong with what you're doing but you don't need to initialize arrays in Mathematica.  So for example you can do:

```
(*Initial Conditions*)
x0 = 1;
v0 = 0;
t0 = 0;
t = 2*Pi;

(*Parameters*)
k = 1;
m = 1;

h = .1;(*Step size*)
n = IntegerPart[(t - t0)/h];(*Number of steps*)
(*Miscellenous For Drawing*)
tList = {t0};
xList = {x0};
vList = {v0};
x = x0;
v = v0;

For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
  vdot = -(k*x)/m;(*Linear Momentum Balance Equation*)
  x = x + v*h;(*Euler's Method*)
  v = v + vdot*h;(*Euler's Method*)
  AppendTo[tList, i*h];
  AppendTo[xList, x];
  AppendTo[vList, v]];

txList = Transpose[{tList, xList}];
ListPlot[txList]
```